# I have an old boiler with no "C" terminal for wifi thermostat

Tags: nest

I have a nest thermostat that need a C cable. I have a Vaillant boiler serial number GA92-120 SP that doesn't have a C connector.

[image]

The boiler has only two wires connected from the thermostat to the boiler. Black wire connected to "T" connector and white wire connected to "TV" connector. In the middle between "T" and "TV" has a double connector with the letters "W" at the top and "Z" on the bottom but no wire connected.

There is a third wire color red that is not connected to anything. Can I use the red wire as a "C" wire? If yes, where in the boiler can I connect this wire?

[image]

[image]

Another option is to use a "Google Nest Power Connector." Since there is no C wire connector in the boiler, it doesn't give instructions to install it. If I use the Google Nest Power Connector," how can I connect it myself?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nest can not control that without some modifications.

Nest needs 24 vac transformer coming from that control board.

So you need to install 24vac transformer which will also give you the C wirer.

Comment: We have 10000 "no C wire" questions here. Have none of them provided an answer for you?

Comment: What make/model is that controller? (I'm suspecting it's a Honeywell aquastat from the looks of things, but can't verify the model number from here!)

Comment: @FreeMan No, I didn't find the answer on all the "no C wire" questions here. I did looked before posting my question.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The cover says Honeywell. I couldn't find any other name on it.

Comment: @LunnaJ -- is there not a label on the inside of the cover that says more?

Comment: @Ruskes Yes, I decided to use the option of installing a 24 vac transformer directly to the thermostat and that worked. I connected one of the wires from the 24 vac transformer to C and the second wire from the transformer to R. I have two wires connected to R now. The first one from the boiler and the second from the 24 vac transformer.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You're right inside the cover says Aquastat. I had to look on one of the other boilers. Mine doesn't have a cover. All three boilers are the same type.

Comment: @LunnaJ all fine now

Comment: @LunnaJ can you post a photo of the labeling on the inside of the cover then please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added the picture of the cover for the Honeywell Aquastat.

Comment: @rukes What your saying is that the boiler has no C connector? Would I be able to use something like the Google nest power connector accessory? https://www.amazon.com/Google-Nest-Power-Connector-Accessories/dp/B093TRFQWP/ref=sr_1_3?crid=64VETL37AHXP&keywords=google+nest+connector&qid=1665799290&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjU4IiwicXNhIjoiMC4yNiIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDkifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=google+next+con%2Caps%2C2988&sr=8-3

Comment: @LunnaJ you said you already used separate transformer and it worked. Yes you can use Goole Nest-power for that

Comment: @ruskes Yes, I used a separate transformer, but I would prefer to use something directly connected to the boiler instead of having a cable running from the thermostat to the outlet in the wall. Would you happen to know where to connect the cables for the Google Nest Power? The instructions doesn't explain for my boiler.

Answer (score -1):

### The L8148E *can* provide a C wire

Your "controller" is a Honeywell L8148E Aquastat Relay.  While the [L8148's installation instructions](https://documents.alpinehomeair.com/product/L8148Instructions.pdf) don't explicitly discuss the C-wire situation, it's clear from the schematics that the Z terminal can be used to land a C wire, provided that your thermostat doesn't draw more than 1.2A of 24V power, which is generally not an issue for most electronic thermostats.

Comment: Can the DVer explain please? only reason I DV'd the other answer was because it was incorrect...